# Turn page compression off in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I have a table in a MariaDB database with:

```
`PAGE_COMPRESSED`='ON'
```

I'm looking for a way to make it off without recreating it with an `"ALTER TABLE"`. I read the [official documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-page-compression/) but couldn't find a way.
Does anyone have any ideas about it?

Comment: Why? Also, the docs you linked say you can set it to `none` in the [Configuring the InnoDB Page Compression Algorithm](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-page-compression/#configuring-the-innodb-page-compression-algorithm) section.

Comment: @J.D. I need to change the compression setting for one table. The setting in the schema was `PAGE_COMPRESSED`='ON'.   As far as I understand, this setting is for the entire database, not just a table.

Answer (score 1):

> InnoDB page compression can be enabled for just individual InnoDB tables

-- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-page-compression/#enabling-innodb-page-compression

In general, what you specify on `CREATE DATABASE` becomes the 'default' for any *subsequent* `CREATE TABLEs` in that database.  And, in general, such settings can be overridden for the newly created table.

Also, in general, anything specified on `CREATE TABLE` (explicitly or inherited from `CREATE DATABASE`) can be modified via `ALTER TABLE`.

So, in general, search the reference manual in those locations for what is possible.  Caution:  There may be exceptions relating to the Engine declared for the table.